# Magento 2 : Run Dependency using Contoller and helper

Tags: magento2

Helper :-

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Helper;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
       public function getStoreConfig()
       {
               echo 'This is Dependency Injection';
       }
}
```

Controller:-

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Dependency;

use \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Helper\Data;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;

class Dependency extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
       public function __construct(Data $helper)
       {
               $this->helper = $helper;
       }
       public function execute()
       {
               $this->helper->getStoreConfig();
               exit();
       }
}
```

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: controller not running in fronted

Comment: 1. What is your controller path? And what you are trying to run the controller on front-end.

Comment: https://local.magento245.com/helloworld/index/Dependency path is ok I have created multiple controller in same folder all are working ex: https://local.magento245.com/helloworld/index/test

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use like this

Helper :-

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Helper;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
       public function getStoreConfig()
       {
               echo 'This is Dependency Injection';
       }
}
```

Controller:-

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Dependency;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;

class Dependency extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
        protected $helper;

       public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Helper\Data $helper)
       {
               $this->helper = $helper;
               parent::__construct($context);
       }

       public function execute()
       {
               $this->helper->getStoreConfig();
               exit();
       }
}
```

Comment: Nope again It's showing Whoops, our bad...The page you requested was not found

Comment: Here is working as expected, even tested on Magento's latest version... What URL are you going to hit in the browser?

Comment: Modified code...

Comment: Please ensure, you run compiled again after added code.

Comment: yes I compiled successfully can you share your URL link

Comment: I am working on localhost, not global URL but yes I can show you screenshot
https://tinyurl.com/2eb5hmr2

Comment: not working in my pc

Comment: Can you please share the code again... either screenshot of the code.. so I can assist you well.

Comment: see I uploaded screenshot in ans

Comment: I can not see, where you have put it.

Comment: share your mail id I'll share you screenshot and code not able to post here

Comment: navneet.sharma@dotsquares.com

Comment: Did you send screenshots on email ?

Comment: yes just shared

Comment: As I see your code, your code is not up to date with my code which I shared...

Comment: ok please send me as soon as possible

Comment: Sent, kindly check

Comment: Hiren, if you are satisfied with my answer please upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your calling path is this one :

> https://local.magento245.com/helloworld/index/dependency

Your controller file code is this :

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

use \Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Helper\Data;
use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;

class Dependency extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
       public function __construct(Data $helper)
       {
               $this->helper = $helper;
       }
       public function execute()
       {
               $this->helper->getStoreConfig();
               exit();
       }
}
```

Comment: getting this error:-
Error: Class "Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Helper\Data" not found in /var/www/html/magento245/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:121
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/magento245/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject()
 and many more errors

Comment: Then check what is the path of your helper.